# Linearly Transform Conditioning Variable in Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Is the following statement true: $\mathrm{E}[y |x,z]=\mathrm{E}[y |x,x+z]$? If yes, could this be extended to $\mathrm{E}[y |x,z]=\mathrm{E}[y |ax,bx+cz]$ for all $a,b,c\neq 0$? Or even $\mathrm{E}[y |x,z]=\mathrm{E}[y |g_1(x),g_2(x,z)]$ for strict monotonic $g_1,g_2$?

I have the following intuition: As long as we have the information on $x$ (say, $x = t_1$), the additional knowledge in $x+z$ (say, $x+z=t_2$) should give as much information as the additional knowledge in $z$ (since $z=t_2-x=t_2-t_1$). Is this intuition correct? Unfortunately, I cannot find any relevant formal statement.

Comment: My intuition would be that if you know $x$ and $x+z$, you also know $z$ (second minus first = $z$), so the information you are conditioning on is the same. The same is true for your second example, as long as you know $a,b,c$. For the third one, if you can recover $x,z$ from $g_1(x), g_2(x, z)$ (which involves also knowing the functions $g_1, g_2$) then I would say that the conditional expectations are the same. Perhaps you could make an argument showing that the sigma algebra generated by those variables are the same, hence the cond. exectation is the same

Comment: @Ant Thanks a lot for your quick reply! I also had the same intuition, but unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge of measure-theoretic probability theory to formally prove/falsify these statements (or find relevant statements online). So it would be helpful if someone could point out any reference.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and they follow easily from the general definition of conditional expectation w.r.t.  a $\sigma-$ algebra. For the first one you only need the fact that $\sigma (x,z)=\sigma (x,x+z)$ which  easy to verify. For  the second one you need the fact that $\sigma (x,z)=\sigma (ax,bx+cz)$. Intutively, the information conatined in $(x,z)$ is same as the one contained in $(x, x+z)$ and a similar thing holds in the second case.